# Name resolution of functions inside templates instantiated with qualified types

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, overloading, name-lookup

Consider the following C++ code example:

```
namespace n
{
    struct A {};
}

struct B {};

void foo(int) {}

template<typename T>
void quux()
{
    foo(T());
}

void foo(n::A) {}
void foo(B) {}


int main()
{
    quux<n::A>(); // Error (but works if you comment out the foo(int) declaration)
    quux<B>();    // Works

    return 0;
}
```

As indicated in the comment, the template instantiation `quux<n::A>()` causes a compiler error (on GCC 4.6.3):

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘void quux() [with T = n::A]’:
foo.cpp:22:16:   instantiated from here
foo.cpp:13:5: error: cannot convert ‘n::A’ to ‘int’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void foo(int)’
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on? I would have expected for it to work the same as with `quux<B>()`. It must have something to do with when `foo` is considered dependent. Unfortunately my C++ foo is not good enough. The example compiles fine, when the `foo(int)` declaration is not present, which is also surprising to me.

Any hints, explanations and workarounds are welcome.

**Update 1:**

I do not want to (read cannot) move the declaration of `foo(n::A)` before the definition of `quux` (which would avoid the error).

**Update 2:**

Thanks for David for pointing out the related question [Template function call confused by function with wrong signature declared before template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223278/template-function-call-confused-by-function-with-wrong-signature-declared-before). The accepted answer by Johannes Schaub - litb proposes a wrapper class solution, that would also work in my case as a workaround. However, I'm not 100% happy with it.

**Update 3:**

I solved the issue by putting the definition of `foo(n::A)` in namespace `n`. Thanks for the helpful answers of Jesse Good and bames53 that not only point out the relevant sections of the standard, but also provide alternative solutions. Thanks to David Rodríguez - dribeas for his explanation when I did not understand the proposed solutions properly and all other contributors.

Comment: Move the `quux` *body* to a later position in the code, *after* all the names `foo` have been declared.

Comment: Yes, that solves the error. However in my real program that is not possible/desired.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That might or not be an option. Clang++ yields a more informative message: *error: call to function 'foo' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup*. Now you will need to find where the lookup for that particular expression is defined in the standard :) --possible workaround: move `foo(n::A)` to the `n` namespace

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template function call confused by function with wrong signature declared before template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223278/template-function-call-confused-by-function-with-wrong-signature-declared-before)

Comment: you cannot even have forward declarations of foo before the definition of quux?

Comment: @didirec: No. Think of `quux()` as `write(std::vector<T>)` and `foo(n::A)` as `write(n::A)`. I want the vector version in a common header file, to use in the print definitions of other print functions all around the place.

Comment: What about move the body of `quux()` after your `main()` function and keep its signature in the same place?

Comment: @David: Not sure whether it is a duplicate yet. But definitely strongly related. It seems I do not quite understand dependent name lookup right. I'm trying to read up in the standard sections pointed out in that related post and Jesse Good's answer below.

Comment: @VictorHugo: Not a viable solution, thanks. Think of `quux` as being defined in a header file.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thanks, I need to find out exactly how argument dependent lookup works. Moving `foo` into the namespace `n` is not an option. Moreover, it does not solve the problem, but rather results in `quux<B>` not working either and also removing the `foo(int)` will then also not solve the issue but rather result in an error and template definition (because now the `n::foo` name is not dependent, because it is a qualified name).

Comment: @NikolausDemmel: I am not sure you understood the proposed change: move `foo(n::A)` into the `n` namespace (leave `foo(B)` where it is, that is in the same namespace as `B`). Do not make a qualified call to `foo` (i.e. leave `foo(T())`, do not make it `n::foo(T())`). That should fix it (assuming that you can move `foo(n::A)` into `namespace n`)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Aha, you are right. I misinterpreted your proposal. In fact this is very workable in my case and solves the problem. Thank you! If you want to add it as an answer, I will accept that answer. Otherwise I will accept Jesse Good's answer (as he explains why it does not work) and point out your solution in an update to my question.

Comment: @NikolausDemmel: Jesse's answer actually explains what the issue is and also hints at the solution with the snippet where `void foo(A)` is moved to the `n` namespace. You should accept his answer.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You are right again. I'm too tired. Anyway, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the rule is 14.6.4.2p1:

> For a function call that depends on a template parameter, the
> candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1,
> 3.4.2, 3.4.3) except that:
>
> — For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1) or qualified name lookup (3.4.3), only
> function declarations from the template definition context are found.
>
> — For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only
> function declarations found in either the template definition context
> or the template instantiation context are found.

`void foo(n::A) {}` is **not visible** in the template definition context because it comes after and `foo` is not in the same namespace as `n::A`. So it needs to be either visible *before* the template definition or included in the same namespace like below:

```
namespace n
{
    void foo(n::A) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint and references to the standard. I think I'm getting close, however I still don't quite understand. The fact the `quux<B>()` works is because `foo` is in the same namespace as `B`, thus `foo` is found in the associated namespace (global in the example) during lookup for instantiation context? `quux<A>()` does not work, because `foo` is not found in the associated namespace (which is only `n`)? Why does it work if `foo(int)` is commented out?

Comment: I just found a solution. If I call `::quux<n::A>(T)`, then it works. My explanation would be that the explicit qualification makes the global namespace an associated namespace. Does that make sense? Is there a solution that could be part of the definition of quux, not the use of quux? **Update:** That was bogus, it doesn't actually work.

Comment: On top of the question of why it works if `foo(int)` is commented out, I'd like to find out if there is a way/workaround that adds the namespace of the definition of `quux` (i.e. `::`) or the point of instantiation of `quux<n::A>` (also `::`) to the associated namespaces that are search in instantiation context?

Comment: And one last thing. This associated namespace lookup (3.4.2) is the Koenig lookup, right?

Comment: It shouldn't work if `foo(int)` is commented out ([see here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2bb1dbe3f1427ae3b9d638919dbfb710)). Another name for argument dependent lookup (ADL) is Koenig lookup after the person who proposed it to the C++ standards committee.

Answer (score 1):

The error my compiler gives is:

```
main.cpp:11:5: error: call to function 'foo' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
    foo(T());
    ^
main.cpp:18:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'quux<n::A>' requested here
    quux<n::A>(); // Error (but works if you comment out the foo(int) declaration)
    ^
main.cpp:14:6: note: 'foo' should be declared prior to the call site or in namespace 'n'
void foo(n::A) {}
     ^
```

Which makes it clear what the problem is.

Commenting out `void foo(int)` *does not* make it work however; that's just a bug/extension in your compiler.

You mention that you can't define `void foo(n::A)` before `quux()`, however when you say in the comments that you can't define it inside namespace `n`, the reasons you give don't seem to apply. This should fix the problem without the other problems you mention.

```
template<typename T>
void quux()
{
    foo(T());
}

namespace n {
    void foo(n::A) {}
}
using n::foo; // in case there's any other code that depends on getting foo(n::A) from the global namespace

void foo(B) {} // this stays in the global namespace
```

---

If you can't move the definition of `void foo(n::A)` to where it works with proper two-phase lookup (again, either before `quux()` *or* inside namespace `n`) there's a sort of hacky solution which may work for you: forward declare the proper overload of `foo()` *inside* `quux()`.

```
template<typename T>
void quux()
{
    void foo(T);
    foo(T());
}
```

The function eventually must be defined inside the same namespace as `quux()` and it has to match the 'generic' forward declaration.

---

Or there's another alternative. It's only been fairly recent that most C++ compilers started offering correct two-phase name lookup, so there's a lot of code out there that isn't correct but which compilers want to support. If you can't change your code then it may be a good candidate for enabling a compatibility compiler option; my compiler takes the flag `-fdelayed-template-parsing` to disable two-phase name lookup and instead always look names up in the instantiation context.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. Your first solution is actually what I have now implemented (thanks to David Rodríguez - dribeas and Jesse Good). When I said I could not put `foo(n::A)` in the `n` namespace I did not understand the solution yet. Thanks also for the two alternative solutions, despite me not needing them in this instance.

Comment: What compiler are you using? The error message is clearly a lot superior to gcc.