# Using functions from global namespace in a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am using a library that is under a namespace, let's call it Hello.

```cpp
namespace Hello {

template<class T>
void World(std::ostream& os, const T& t) {
    os << t;
}

}
```

The `class T` is something like `std::array<int,10>` and I also write an ostream overload function for it. However, calling `Hello::World(arr)` leads to compile errors that say the compiler cannot find the overload for `operator<<()`.

After some search, I come up with a solution that explains this situation.
[How does the operator overload resolution work within namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359562/how-does-the-operator-overload-resolution-work-within-namespaces) and [Name resolution of functions inside templates instantiated with qualified types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316727/name-resolution-of-functions-inside-templates-instantiated-with-qualified-types).

So we can simplify the situation like this.

```
void f(int) {}
void f(int,int) {}

namespace Hello {
    using ::f;
    void f(int,int,int) {}
    void World()
    {
        f(100);
        f(100, 200);
        f(100, 200, 300);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Hello::World();
    return 0;
}
```

Without the `using ::f;` line, this code fails to be compiled since the name `f` can hide **ALL of the functions** with the same name in the global namespace.

Now that this is my problems:

1. Since `namespace Hello { .... }` is in the library, I shall not modify it. That is, I cannot modify the implementation inside `World()`. The only solution is to put a line `namespace Hello { using ::f; }` somewhere in my code. Is it a good practice, or there is a more elegant solution?
2. In this example, can I only import `f(int)` and not `f(int,int)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good practice, or there is a more elegant solution?

IMHO, you can use it with third party library. It is clear and expressive enough. It would be better if you could write:

```cpp
void World() {
    ::f(100);           // f from global namespace
    ::f(100, 200);      // f from global namespace
    f(100, 200, 300);   // f NOT from global namespace
}
```

because then it is clearly visible which function **is** and which **is not** from the global namespace but this solution does not work for you since you cannot modify implementation of `World` function.

> Can I only import `f(int)` and not `f(int, int)`?

Yes. You can do the following in order to import only `f(int)` function:

```cpp
void f(int) {}

namespace Hello {
    using ::f;    // only void f(int) is defined before this line
                  // therefore, it is the only overload being imported to the Hello namespace
}

void f(int,int) {}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:3,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:3,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:3,selectionStartLineNumber:20,startColumn:3,startLineNumber:20),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Avoid+f(int)+%7B%7D%0A%0Anamespace+Hello+%7B%0A++++using+::f%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+f(int,int)+%7B%7D%0A%0Anamespace+Hello+%7B%0A++++void+f(int,int,int)+%7B%7D%0A++++void+World()%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++f(100)%3B%0A++++++++f(100,+200)%3B%0A++++++++f(100,+200,+300)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++Hello::World()%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

**UPDATE**

If you want to import only one overload of an `operator<<`, not an ordinary function, then you could wrap each overload in a separate namespace like this:

```cpp
namespace XX {

struct X {
    int x;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, X const& x) {
    return os;
}

}

namespace YY {

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Y const& y) {
    return os;
}

struct Y {
    double y;
};

}

namespace Hello {
    using ::XX::X;
    using ::XX::operator<<;
    using ::YY::Y;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRABmcwAdUCwuto9QxMzUh8/NTobO0cjFzdPRWVMVQCGAmZiAiDjU04klUjadMyCaIdnVxBeBQysnJD82tLy2PjqgEpFVANiZA4Acil3W2RDLABqcXcddVriTGYjaexxAAYAQWHR8cwpmYV5xeX3Vc31jdolzAUvZn6JgA1HqYB2WXPN%2BYNVJ7ePjYTIETWwECYAD2mAPErwAIlCLhdaugQCBfAQFkspAA2CaoLyuZhEYjTHSkiDI1HozHLSS43ykP5oWi1HEQjr/C7AiYLAi9Wh4hQI85wxEi%2BGfS7XW73PYATTlnMllLRRyxdLxBOIRJIpPJKupxzZDImiuZrI1AE8OTCAdzefzBcKtqLlRifmDFbaucD0D0nOwJpbnTD4e5oeKxVKjDc7g8ABLKVioJWA4EGPyiCao54553cjO2YDZkC5tFanUkmZ68M%2BoGFrOohVNkOurabK4xmUJpMp72bbnfX4ALVT3O5VGTRImAC988DQyGB8CDWrafSK8SazoKQQUaqMUaNSbR%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%2B7FuAmYBkGQCYIHdWgzI5CBcEIEgpkkdx8gmPQcvSjXPA5dTZBkQz6tM0gLJktZrJ4a2ZPcbFsUs%2BzXls7gZJ8gY/NIY7rcFgbgtC8LIvN2KEogJAegILwMPIShstS9LQkwfBiUEM7GBYUbroAd21LwTq9gWApU6ThkkCZc8IBAIVF8XJel2X5eIAxFY6M3oothBFiwNxAK9n2/Yi0uguk4OIqikzzJAa3bY9tYHadl2ZLdj2vfcfyhfH0Ou75gZJC3wOd6niSumm4g/A0bggA%3D%3D%3D).

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I still have some concerns. 1. As I said, since Hello::World is a template library function that I cannot modify (something like boost::whatever), so I cannot not have it call the global one explicitly. 2. Changing the order of declaration is elegant. However, f() is indeed the operator<<, so I would like a solution that can explicitly import only the one I need.

Comment: @johnjohnlys 1. I wrote that I understand you cannot call the global one explicitly. I just mentioned that as an addition. 2. Can you use something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/AmQv2a)?

Comment: Creating another namespace and import that is a brilliant idea! Thanks.